# O que são as pastas "partials" no Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

No Laravel existem pastas "partials" isso é uma convenção? O que devo guardar nessas pastas?

PS: Estou iniciando no mundo Laravel!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Partials faz jus ao termo "parciais", onde se refere a "views parciais".

Supor que você tem um body, neste body você possui: `top header`, `banner`, `menu` e `content`.

`top header`, `banner` e `menu` seriam `views partials`, dividindo o código e deixando mais legível.

Outro exemplo: Você possui uma listagem de produtos, uma table, que se repete em diversas parte do sistema. Você irá repetir código para formatar essa table? Não, você cria uma partial para ela.

`@each('products.list', $products)`

Da uma olhada na documentação: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade